# Can I still attune while flying?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

In a 5th edition campaign I'm trying to run away from an enemy with the loot I have.  If I attune to the item it will grant me a teleport to be gone for good.
I have a cloak of wings, and I have the entire hour of flight time to attune.
The cloak should be doing all the work for me, so **can I attune this item while I am flying?**

Comment: Since opinions are divided, a possibly relevant detail: what is the item you're attempting to attune?

Comment: Another pertinent detail is who or what is pursing you. Can they fly for 60 minutes? If so I don't think autopilot will work.

Answer (score 16):

**No**

> Attuning to an item requires a creature to spend a **Short Rest** focused on only that item while being in physical contact with it (this can’t be the same short rest used to learn the item’s properties). This focus can take the form of weapon practice (for a weapon), **meditation (for a wondrous item)**, or some other appropriate activity. If the Short Rest is interrupted, the attunement attempt fails. Otherwise, at the end of the Short Rest, the creature gains an intuitive understanding of how to activate any magical properties of the item, including any necessary Command words.

(Page 137 *Dungeon Master's Guide*) and

> A short rest is a period of downtime, at least 1 hour long, during which a character does nothing more strenuous than eating, drinking, reading, and tending to wounds.

(Page 186 *Player Handbook*)

Since flying is definitely more strenuous than eating/drinking, you cannot attune while flying.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61567/discussion-on-answer-by-timi-can-i-still-attune-while-flying).

Answer (score -1):

### Yes.

If the item caused some sort of strain or caused exhaustion, you wouldn't be able to. But like a Ring or Cloak of Protection, the magic item is doing the work for you, so your character can very easily concentrate on the requirements of attuning to an item.

In the **PHB pg 186** under the heading *Short Rest*:

> A short rest is a period of downtime, at least 1 hour long, during which a character does nothing more strenuous than eating, drinking, reading, and tending to wounds.

Immediately following this is an example of strenuous activity under the heading *Long Rest*:

> If the rest is interrupted by a period of strenuous activity—at least 1 hour of walking, fighting, casting spells, or similar adventuring activity—
>   the characters must begin the rest again to gain any benefit from it.

This very clearly illustrates that strenuous activity is something you have to actively engage in. Furthermore, the requirement for attunement actually includes strenuous activity as part of the action you take to attune to the item.

Specifically, **DMG pg 137**:

> This focus can take the form of weapon practice (for a weapon), meditation (for a wondrous item), or some other appropriate activity.

Practicing with a weapon most definitely does not fall under the short rest definition provided above. This *suggests,* but does not state, that if you choose to spend the rest attuning to an item, you wouldn't also benefit from the rest itself since you were busy exerting yourself for the duration of that short rest and thus were not able to benefit from it.

Now, I personally wouldn't do that as a DM, but 5e is more about rulings than rules. RAW, nothing under short rest says you can't attune while flying using a magical item.

Comment: Practicing isn't strenuous; you can stop whenever you like, push yourself as hard as you want. You have no time limitations in which to dodge or parry, and you don't even have to include them in your practice session because it's not specific to a weapon.

Comment: While I agree, it does not conform to the short rest text. As such, I would call it "strenuous" activity. Your game, your rules. I have said my piece using the book rules with respect to this. Magical flight = yes to attune because you arent doing the work.

Comment: If walking is continued strenuous than flying definitely is. Flying speed is still movement, and even if you're hovering in place, you're still counteracting gravity.

Comment: If it was self powered flight I agree. These are magic items we are talking about.

Comment: @VoromirKadien - I don't understand your objection. That quote has nothing to do with short rests, and I explained in the answer why I was referencing it. Incidentally, a short rest is *at least* 1 hour long.

Answer (score -1):

### **Maybe.**

That's going to take a DM ruling on your cloak of wings in regards to how it works. Attuning to an item requires a short rest:

> A short rest is a period of downtime, at least 1 hour long, during
>   which a character does nothing more strenuous than eating, drinking,
>   reading, and tending to wounds.

How, specifically, this cloak makes you fly becomes important, then. If this requires some concentration on your part to stay off the ground, then no. If you can absent-mindedly stay airborne, then yes.

My personal ruling would be no - this cloak and it's wings become an extension of your body that requires, at minimum, a mundane amount of thought an exercise to flap the wings and fly; like walking. But your DM may rule differently. Press your DM to rule on *how* this cloak makes you fly and I think the answer to your question will become obvious.